# Annotate Gem ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, annotate

I am having some problems with the annotate gem.  I am running ruby 2.3, and rails 5beta3. bundle install seems to work just fine but when I go to call on the annotate command I get this...

```
ruby@echobase:~/crash$ annotate
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/annotate-2.7.0/lib/annotate.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_
access (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/annotate-2.7.0/lib/annotate.rb:12:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/annotate-2.7.0/lib/annotate.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/annotate-2.7.0/bin/annotate:18:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/annotate-2.7.0/bin/annotate:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/annotate:22:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/annotate:22:in `<main>'
```

not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run the gem from terminal then try `bundle exec annotate User` to use your bundled gems rather than the system gems. You need to provide the model information after `annotate`.

Comment: Using `rake db:migrate` sometimes works when direct `annotate` fails.
For Rails 5 and later, you may need to use devel branch from github:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/41011908-rake-12-0-0-support